# If $(x+y-7)[z(x+y)+24]=(y+z-7)[x(y+z)+24]=(z+x-7)[y(z+x)+24]$, find $x^2+y^2+z^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math, systems-of-equations

> Let x, y, z be pairwise distinct real numbers, if $$(x+y-7)[z(x+y)+24]=(y+z-7)[x(y+z)+24] $$ $$=(z+x-7)[y(z+x)+24]$$, find $x^2+y^2+z^2$

I've tried many ways but couldn't find a working way to solve it. I tried letting $(x+y-7)[z(x+y)+24] = k$ and $t = x + y + z$ but none of these gives useful transformation as far as I can see. Could somebody shed some lights on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Somehow I feel the question is not ordered corectly

Comment: Yes it seems so. But it seems that my mathjax code is correct, could you take a look at it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

let $f_z=(x+y-7)(z(x+y)+24)$,$f_y,f_x$ defined similarly $$f_x=f_y=f_z=k$$ $$f_z-f_y=0\to -(y - z) (x^2 - 7 x - y z - 24)=0$$  so $$x^2-7x-yz=24$$and similarly for others yield  $$p_x=p_y=p_z=24$$ where $p_x=x^2-7x-yz$ and others defined similarly $$p_x-p_y=0\to (x-y)(x+y+z-7)=0$$ so $$x+y+z=7\to z=7-x-y$$ Plug this into orginal condition to get $$z^3-7z^2-24z-k=x^3-7x^2-24x-k=y^3-7y^2-24y-k=0$$ thus $x,y,z$ are the roots of cubic $$p(t)=t^3-7t^2-24t-k$$ Now by vieta you can easily find $x^2+y^2+z^2$

Comment: @cosmo5 please do,I am bound to have made typo's /calculation error

Comment: @cosmo5 thanks I saw your solution,but how can we take $x+y+z=fixed$? I am missing something?

Comment: @cosmo5 Then I disagree,since $S=f(x,y,z)$ and the polynomila itself is a function of $z$ I dont see why we could Isolate them,If you prove that $S=fixed$ then I am with you

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: @cosmo5 I saw your edit,but you find that $S=7$ after assuming that $P(x)=x^3-x^2(2S-7)......$ but the problem is that $S$ contains $x$ so I have a little doubt whther we can simply apply vieta.Note that you rpoved $S=7=fixed$ after assuming $P(x)=x^3-x^2(2S-7)+stuff$

Comment: I see your point. I'll leave it up for further comments.

Comment: @cosmo5 sure please do,I am not completely sure that your solution is right or wrong,but I have a little doubt over there ,I am considering asking a question with this concept Actually I started out with this idea but i had a little doubt overthere and gave up in the middle.Anyway thank you for taking time to answer my questions

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore Cosmo's solution is correct. We are technically starting with the assumption that such distinct numbers exist, and hence so does $S$ which is a constant, and then creating a polynomial with the constant $S$.

Comment: @CalvinLin my point is just because $x,y,z$ are pairwise distinct that doesnt mean we cant find another triplet satisfying conditions so that $x+y+z$ yields a diffrent value

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore But that doesn't matter. Every solution set $(x^*, y^*, z^*)$ will have their own $S^*$ to work with. Of course, there is no guarantee the answer is a constant, in which case the answer would be a range. From Cosmo's solution, you can see why $x+y+z=S$ is uniquely defined, and hence so is $xy+yz+zx = S^2 - 7S - 24$, and hence so is $x^2+y^2+z^2$. However, $xyz$ can be different due to the "+ constant" in cosmo's solution. (Of course, we have to check the discriminant to ensure real roots per the question.) So, another question could be to ask for the range of $xyz$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S=x+y+z$. Given is
$$P(x)=(S-x-7)\{x(S-x)+24\}$$
$$=x^3-x^2(2S-7)+x(S^2-7S-24)+24S-168$$
has same value as $P(y), P(z)$.

This means $x,y,z$ are roots of the polynomial, $P(x)+\text{constant}$.

By Vieta's, sum of roots is $S=2S-7 \Rightarrow S=7$. Also
$$xy+yz+zx=-(7^2-7\cdot 7 -24)=24$$

Hence $x^2+y^2+z^2=7^2-2\cdot 24=1$

Answer (score 1):

I write $u = y + z$, $v = z + x$, $w = x + y$ and $s = (u + v + w) / 2 (= x + y + z)$.

The equation becomes $$(u - 7)(us - u^2 + 24) = (v - 7)(vs - v^2 + 24) = (w - 7)(ws - w^2 + 24).$$

Taking the difference of the first and the second term, we get $$(u - v)((u + v - 7)s - (u^2 + uv + v^2 - 7(u + v) - 24)) = 0.$$

Since $x, y, z$ are all different, we know that $u, v, w$ are all different. This leads to $$(u + v - 7)s = u^2 + uv + v^2 - 7(u + v) - 24 \tag{1}$$ and symmetrically $$(v + w - 7)s = v^2 + vw + w^2 - 7(v + w) - 24.$$ Taking the difference of the above two identities, we get $$(u - w)s = (u - w)(u + w + v - 7)$$ which leads to $$s = 2s - 7$$ and thus $s = 7$.

Now (1) becomes $$u^2 + uv + v^2 - 14(u + v) + 25 = 0. \tag{2}$$ Taking the symmetric sum of (2), we get $$2\sum u^2 + \sum uv - 56s + 75 = 0. \tag{3}$$

If we write $t = \sum x^2$, then we have $\sum xy = (s^2 - t)/2 = (49 - t)/2$. It follows that $$\sum u^2 = \sum (y^2 + 2yz + z^2) = 2\sum x^2 + 2\sum xy = 49 + t$$ and $$\sum uv = ((2s)^2 - \sum u^2) / 2 = (147 - t) / 2.$$

Thus the equation (3) reads $$2(49 + t) + (147 - t) / 2 = 317$$ and we deduce that $t = 97$.

---

Finally, it is possible to give examples of $x, y, z$ satisfying these equalities.

E.g. $x = 3, y = 2 + 2\sqrt{10}, z = 2 - 2\sqrt{10}$.